# why my sessionStorage gives { 'object Object': '' }

Tags: javascript, node.js, ajax, object

I have a query I'm passing data from one page to other using local storage. after that i take that data and i make a string . Then i pass that json string to sessionstorage to use as data for my ajax request. but i'm always getting this data as { 'object Object': '' }.

my code ,

```
const parsedData = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('myData'));
    console.log(parsedData,"parsedData");
    
   
 
    parsedData.data.rows.forEach((result, idx) => {
      
     var a = result.master_id;
     var b = result.session_name;
     console.log(a,b,"a","b")

    var userData = {"pid":a,"session" :b};
     console.log( userData ,"userData");  
   
     sessionStorage.setItem('user', JSON.stringify(userData)); 
  
................. then i access this data in another function,
 function graphApi(){
    
     const apiValue = (sessionStorage.getItem('user'));
    
        console.log(apiValue,"apivalue new")
      /*var dat ={
        "pid":"WEB506",
        "session":"WEB506_09092021_M1_S2.csv"
        };*/
       
     
       $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        data:  apiValue ,   
         url: "http://localhost:5000/file",
        success: function (data) {
          console.log(data)
        },
         error: function(err){
          alert(err);
          }
```

Plese help, im stuck with for some time now.

in addition, this is my controller api,

```
File: async (req, res, next) => {
  console.log('---------------');
  console.log( req.body); this is where i get { 'object Object': '' }
  console.log('---------------');
  try{
    if(!req.body){
      throw new Error("sorry no data, error occured")
    }

   const {pid, session} = req.body;
 
   const user = await models.graph_data.findAndCountAll({
    attributes: [
      "document"
    ],
```

Comment: You are setting `.setItem('user')` in every loop. It is being overwritten every time. In the end, only the last value will remain

Comment: so you suggest?

Comment: Where are you getting `{ 'object Object': '' }`? There are three `console.log` in this code

Comment: Well I suggest to _not_ overwrite the same session variable in every loop :) I'm just pointing out the obvious

Comment: i have added it in my question. my req.body gives  { 'object Object': '' } , ie my ajax is sending it right?

Comment: Aaaah, so there's a _fourth_ `console.log`, the relevant one, that you hadn't put in your original question! What are you getting from `console.log(apiValue)`? Is it correct? If it is, you are missing JSON parsing in Node. Did you add `app.use( express.json() )`?

Comment: Yes i added  app.use( express.json() ). my  console.log(apiValue) is  {pid: 'WEB506', session: 'WEB506_09092021_M1_S1.csv'} 'apiValue'

Comment: Interesting. Try to parse `apiValue` before sending it to the back-end, with `JSON.parse(apiValue )`, and send that in your Ajax call

Comment: i tried  that too, but hard luck nothing worked so far.

Answer (score 0):

You're consoling the whole arrayof objects not a single object
try

```
console.log(data.pid) or console.log(data.session)
```

Comment: but bro im getting { '{"pid":"WEB506","session":"WEB506_09092021_M1_S1.csv"}': '' } this as my out in req.body in my api. that means in ajax data this value is sending. right?

Answer (score 0):

Try clearing your sesionStorage and try again. The code

```
{ 'object Object': '' }
```

is a sign that you used a reference value eg JSON object as a key.
However, your code doesn't seem to do that.
Try clearing your sessionStorage and try again

Comment: i tried that already

Comment: That's a comment, not an answer...